# How to organize div to look like a table?

Tags: html, css

I have form with multiple input fields and I would like to organize them like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/58ea82gj/2/

Layout above used table structure. I'm creating from layout and all of these above I would need to create using div. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="formItem">
    <div class="frRow">
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>Results</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="frRow">
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>Ear</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>250</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>500</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>750</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>1000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>1500</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>2000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>3000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>4000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>6000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>8000</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="frRow">
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>SRT<br>SAT</span>
        </div>
        <div class="frCell">
            <span>Recognition</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My div structure is still far away from desired layout. I have used css display-table on each div element. Here is CSS:

```
div.frRow {
    margin: 5px;
    display: table;
}
div.frCell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.frCell span {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to layout this type of form fields. Please let me know how I can get desired layout or if there is better way to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table structure is composed of `table > row > cell` so :

You neet to set the container **formItem**  to `display:table` and the row **frRow**  to `display:table-row` to get the table structure

```css
div.formItem {
  margin: 5px;
  display: table;
}

div.frRow {
  display: table-row;
}

div.frCell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

div.frCell span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="formItem">
  <div class="frRow">
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>Results</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="frRow">
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>Ear</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell" style="width:100px;min-width:100px;">
      <span>250</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>500</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>750</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>1000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>1500</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>2000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>3000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>4000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>6000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="frCell">
      <span>8000</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="frRow">
    <div class="formItem">
      <div class="frCell">
        <span>SRT<br>SAT</span>
      </div>
      <div class="frCell">
        <span>Recognition</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do row-span and col-span on div elements?

Comment: @espresso_coffee for the colspan you can wrap the wanted cells inside a div with `display:table` property see my edit

Comment: Ok I have one question. On one of the div cell elements I tried to set unique width for example 150px. This affected all div cells in that column. Why and how this can be fixed?

Comment: @espresso_coffee setting a fixed width on a cell will affect all cells on the same columns because that's the expected behavior of the table structure, now you should see if table structure is really what you need!

Answer (score -1):

in your css add this

```
 formItem{display:table;}
frRow{display:table-row;}
frCell{display:table-cell}
```